# Get PuTTY sessions from Windows folder

Tags: windows, registry, putty

I have my hard drive from my old workstation, I did not export the PuTTY session from my old machine. I am in a situation that I am not able to boot from it, but I have it as a slave drive.

Is there any way I can scavenge the PuTTY sessions from that hard drive?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The PuTTY sessions are stored in Windows registry in key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SimonTatham\PuTTY
```

If you have a raw file system access only, you have to use some tool that can decode the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` registry file `C:\Users\username\ntuser.dat`.

One freeware tool that can do this is [MiTeC Windows Registry Recovery](http://www.mitec.cz/wrr.html).

---

For details on the process see my guide [How do I transfer my settings to another computer, when source computer is not running anymore?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_transfer_config#offline)

The guide is for transferring settings of WinSCP client, but will work for PuTTY too. Just substitute key path `Software/Martin Prikryl/WinSCP 2` with `Software/SimonTatham/PuTTY`.